# Fetch all records from database and print them through grid one by one

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I want to design a data grid on form and place 2 buttons for print (Print payslip of support staff) and (print payslip of all employees) when user click on any button all records of employees of selected group should be retrieved from SQL database and printed in the grid view format automatically one by one (user shouldn't have to print each record separately).

Could someone please guide me how can I do this.

Comment: Hi Sorath, As you said you are new in the C#.net if you want to learn C#, SQL Server database, SQL Query optimization, Query Performance tuning, and other related technology then you can visit Codingvila, where you can find easy articles with simple code examples.  Link: https://coding-vila.blogspot.com

Comment: Unfortunately this question is too broad for SO. SO questions are intended to to be about a specific programming issue you've encountered.

Comment: I know my Question is long but I just wanted to clear the things that I want to do and the results that I want to achieve. please guide if you can.

Comment: did u get complete this task? I am facing the same probelm now, plz help